# How to make a loading button in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [react](/questions/tagged/react) with [in Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) framework and I was wondering: How can I create a loading button using this framework?

I am looking for something similar to [this](https://dialogs.github.io/dialog-web-components/#buttonnext).

Comment: Do you mean the loading animation in the button?

Comment: @JulesDupont yes I do!

Comment: Are you using material-ui v1 or v0?

Comment: @JulesDupont I am using the latest v1 version with the latest version of react.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no single component that accomplishes this out of the box in material-ui. However, you can implement your own easily using [`CircularProgress`](https://material-ui-next.com/api/circular-progress/).

Assuming you are using material-ui v1, here's a rough example. First, I create a `LoadingButton` that accepts a `loading` prop - if that prop is `true`, I display a `CircularProgress` indicator. It also accepts a `done` prop - if that's true, the button clears the progress indicator and becomes a checkmark to show success.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress';
import Check from 'material-ui-icons/Check';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const LoadingButton = (props) => {
  const { classes, loading, done, ...other } = props;

  if (done) {
    return (
      <Button className={classes.button} {...other} disabled>
        <Check />
      </Button>
    );
  }
  else if (loading) {
    return (
      <Button className={classes.button} {...other}>
        <CircularProgress />
      </Button>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Button className={classes.button} {...other} />
    );
  }
}

LoadingButton.defaultProps = {
  loading: false,
  done: false,
  };

LoadingButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  done: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(LoadingButton);
```

You can use the `LoadingButton` as shown in the following example, which uses `state` to set the appropriate prop on the button.

```
import React from 'react';
import LoadingButton from './LoadingButton';

class ControlledButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { loading: false, finished: false };
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, finished } = this.state;

    const setLoading = !finished && loading;

    return (
      <div>
        <LoadingButton
          loading={setLoading}
          done={finished}
          onClick={() => {
            // Clicked, so show the progress dialog
            this.setState({ loading: true });

            // In a 1.5 seconds, end the progress to show that it's done
            setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ finished: true })}, 1500);
          }}
        >
          Click Me
        </LoadingButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ControlledButton;
```

You can of course tweak the styling and functionality to meet your exact needs.

Comment: That worked! How would you do it with a ... loading style instead of a circular progress :)

Comment: You can see all of the progress indicators built into material-ui [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/progress/). You should be able to just swap them in and out.

Comment: In material-ui there is no such thing like a dot dot dot loading indicator. How we gonna solve that? :-)

Comment: If you're dead set on dotdotdot, you're probably going to need to make your own, because I couldn't find any React library that provides one out of the box. But, material-ui is made according to Material Design - why not just stick with one of the Material Design progress indicators?

Comment: This works, however, it's won't produce a valid HTML. CircularProgress uses a div, which inside of a button makes the HTML invalid.

Answer (score 14):

In the newer versions of Material UI, you can use [`LoadingButton`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#loading-button) component, it's currently in the lab package. This is just a wrapper of the `Button` with a `loading` prop. You can customize the `loadingIndicator` component and its position. See the example below:

```
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';
```

```
<LoadingButton loading={loading}>
  Text
</LoadingButton>
```

```
<LoadingButton
  endIcon={<SendIcon />}
  loading={loading}
  loadingPosition="end"
  variant="contained"
>
  Send
</LoadingButton>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: How do we install `lab` package ?

Comment: @ABAbhi see the installation guide [here](https://mui.com/components/about-the-lab/#installation)