# MUI v5: Do I need to install @emotion/react or @emotion/styled to use sx prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have migrated my project from v4 to v5, I am only using `sx` prop.
I have not installed `@emotion/react` and everything is working fine.
Is there any reason to install `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled`?
because I havent install it and everything is running good.

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.48",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
```

Comment: Can you share me your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install MUI packages without extra configuration, you're using the default style engine powered by emotion, as opposed to the other official style engine that uses [styled-component](https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/#how-to-switch-to-styled-components) which needs more setup.

To use the default style engine, you need to install the 2 emotion packages as outlined in the [installation guide](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Even when you only use the MUI icons from `@mui/icons-material` package, you also need the above 2 packages as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69644912/9449426) answer. The only reason I can think why you don't have any error is because you're not using any MUI components yet, or you're using some unstyled components like the [`UnstyledButton`](https://mui.com/components/buttons/#unstyled) which is a raw component that doesn't have any styles applied to it.

**Edit:** The reason why you can install `@mui/material` without emotion is because it's already installed by `@hookform/devtools` package as seen from the [package.json](https://github.com/react-hook-form/devtools/blob/fd28ebfe7ac4e8f9944a7caef6f7a592246b2608/package.json#L60-L61) here. If you uninstall both packages and only reinstall `@mui/material`, it will complain about missing emotion dependencies again.

```
npm un @mui/material @mui/lab @mui/icons-material @hookform/devtools
npm i @mui/material @mui/lab @mui/icons-material
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response.
I am using MUI components like such as: 
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { Button, Grid } from '@mui/material';
(using sx prop only for the styling.)

I deleted node_modules and npm install again, but everything is running good with no errors, so it is weird I didnt need to install those 2 packages.

Comment: @elam does it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. 
I am using MUI components like buttons, grids, only with sx prop for the styling and everything is running as expected, I just wanted to know why I do not need to install those 2 packages. If I install them , also everything is working fine. 
I have even tried to delete node modules and reinstall packages again, and everything is good. It is weird.

Comment: @elam can you add your `package-lock.json`?

Comment: Of course, my package-lock.json
[link]: (shorturl.at/zBCZ1)
and my package.json
[link]: (shorturl.at/ampFL)

Please tell me if you find anything "weird".
Thank you.

Comment: @elam can you give me a list of commands you use to create the project? what npm version are you using?

Comment: Of course, 
npm version: 6.14.15
node version: 14.18.1
I am using windows 11 and created the project by using:  npx create-react-app my_app

Comment: @elam can you put your devDependencies here too? I'm running out of idea now. You're using npm v6, which should not [auto install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207983/9449426) peer dependencies (emotion packages are peer dependencies of @mui/material package)

Comment: Also, there are no error on my console log while developing my app. I deleted node modules and package-lock and npm install again, but everything is working great , it's weird I though @emotion packages were necessaries.

Comment: Here is my entire package.json file: https://pastebin.com/2CnNkrb4

Comment: Here is one of the custom components I use using @mui/material Button and Grid. 
https://pastebin.com/vVmN2ejt

Comment: @elam unrelated but you can use [`LoadingButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309533/9449426) in v5

Comment: @elam found the problem, see my updated answer :D

Comment: For some reason I did not know dependencies of my dependencies were directly connected to my main project. I just added those @emotion packages directly to my package.json.  Thank you so much for teaching me something new today!